# Would it be inappropriate to direct users to an Area 51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

There are a lot of questions in the Magento category that need flagged to be moved (most of them).

Would it be bad to comment on those posts to head over to the Area 51 page for the Magento proposal?

Comment: Guaranteed to become an obsolete comment, but in the case of someone who could be a quality contributor, I don't think it would be a total waste. But I'm posting this as a comment because I'm not 100% on that... does seem a bit 'noisy'.

Comment: I imagine it would come across that way, but most of these posts kinda tumbleweed out it seems like. Fade off with very few views.

Comment: But by posting on Area51, they will not get any answer until the site goes "beta". Then I guess the people who have a real problem wants a faster answer.

Answer (score 6):

Are the questions off-topic where they're being asked?  That is, are they *being closed* as off-topic where they're at now?  In that case, yes go ahead and comment on closed questions to try and get support for a site where those questions would be on-topic.

Otherwise, if the question is already on-topic where it's at, please don't post links to promote a proposal.  That would seem a little spammy to me if links promoting any other site (even another SE proposal) started popping up just because they were on a related topic.

Comment: Thank you Bill, that's what I was wanting to know. There is quite a large number of questions that are not meant for SO that are magento specific. These _are_ in fact the questions I was talking about. I'll accept this as the answer when it lets me.

Comment: @paperids Sure, no problem.  I'd also suggest you try and restrict promotional commenting to only those *really great* questions that you'd really like to see on the proposed site.  That way you'd be setting a standard for the type of questions and contributors you attract to the new site.  Good luck!

Comment: Meaning, let the bad questions die here.